# Display WooCommerce Product Availability Conditionally

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I have both simple and variable products. I noticed that the stock count is displayed on the product page when the product stock is set to manage.

How do I set the woocommerce-availability to display only when there are 50 or less products in stock?

Something like this perhaps:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'display_availability_conditionally', 10, 2 );
function display_availability_conditionally( $availability, $product ) {

    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->get_stock_quantity() < 50 ) {

    return $availability;
}
}
```

Comment: Code works. Just checking if there is a better way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code. Use the following instead:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'display_availability_conditionally', 10, 2 );
function display_availability_conditionally( $availability, $product ) {
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->get_stock_quantity() > 50 ) {
        $availability = '';
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

or the following similar:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'display_availability_conditionally', 10, 2 );
function display_availability_conditionally( $availability, $product ) {
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->get_stock_quantity() > 50 ) {
        $availability['availability'] = '';
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.